# Django Celery application with timer

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am having a problem with my django celery application. Let's assume that I have two related models - Transaction and Account. I am pushing transactions over my API. What I want to achieve is to calculate the balance for a specified account.

I have a celery task which calculates balance. The problem is that I need a timer per each account, set to eg. 60 seconds. When transaction is coming for the same account timer is set to 60 again. I want to make it this way because I don't want to run the same task many times. When transactions for a specified account will not come for 60 seconds then task should be executed.

Any architectural suggestions how to achieve this? In fact, I only have no idea how to setup these "timers".

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the aproach of [django-celery-transactions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery-transactions). They [subclass the `Task` class](https://github.com/fellowshipofone/django-celery-transactions/blob/master/djcelery_transactions/__init__.py) in order for the execution logic to be customized.

For your case, you should customized `apply_async` to check if there are queued tasks to be executed during the following 60 seconds (for this you will use the [Celery API for *inspecting workers*](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#inspecting-workers)). If there already exists an scheduled task, you can ignore the execution of the current task; if not, set an execution time of 60 seconds in the future and call with it the `super().apply_async(...)` method.